# How to add objects inside object using single array technique

Tags: javascript, function, object

I just want to add objects inside objects dynamically using array technique. I know how do we add Objects - those are `Object[key]` or `Object.key` but suppose I thing I have to add multiple objects dymanically using function

**Note: below example is just for demonstration**

```
let array = ['first','second','third']
let object = {}

function addObject(key) {
  object[key] = "someValue"
}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  addObject(array[i])
}
```

This gives output like this `{ first: 'someValue', second: 'someValue', third: 'someValue'}`. Actually I want my output something like nested object `{first:{second:{third:'somevalue'}}}` not exactly this but a nested object first > second > third.

My Actual question is like how to add objects inside object in this situation. What is the correct syntax for this. Like `object[first][second][third]` is standard way to achieve but I can't add `+` operator in the left side or calling `array(['first.second.third'])`
`

```
function addObject(key) {
  object[key] + [key] = "someValue"
}

or calling

array(['first.second.third'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `reduceRight` to iterate over the array starting from the end. Pass in the final property value as the initial accumulator, so you get `{ third: 'someValue' }` on the first iteration, and return it so it's the new accumulator. On subsequent iterations, do the same thing - create another object enclosing the last returned accumulator.

```js
const array = ['first','second','third']
const nestedValue = 'someValue';
const result = array.reduceRight(
  (a, prop) => ({ [prop]: a }),
  nestedValue
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this ,  I didn't get this well, I have to look it , Is there any way to pass `array(['first.second.third'])` directly so it get everytime. there are also four five six ... and this should be added dynamically.

Comment: It's possible, but a bit more convoluted... extract the first (only) item from the array and then split by periods. `theArr[0].split('.')` then pass to `.reduceRight`.

Comment: I really have to look this first, thanks for your valuable answers.